# Linked List: Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I wanted to try out the example of a linked list on this page: [How to create Linked List using C++](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24684/How-to-create-Linked-list-using-C-C).
This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace s-td;

class node {
public:
    int value;
    node *next;
};

int main() {
    node *head = nullptr;

    node *temp1;
    temp1 = new node();
    temp1->value = 1;
    temp1 = head;

    while(temp1->next!=nullptr) {
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But unfortunately I get a `Segmentation fault`.
I think this part is faulty:

```
while(temp1->next!=nullptr) {
    temp1 = temp1->next;
}
```

Comment: temp1 = head; - you are assigning temp1 = nullptr; you probably want head = temp1;

Comment: Has `temp1->next` been initialised when you are comparing to nullptr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things are wrong with your code:

a) You are assigning `temp1 = head`, which is synonymous to `temp1 = nullptr` in your case

b) You are not initializing `->next` to be `nullptr`, so your while-condition may or may not be satisfied (undefined behaviour)

Answer (score 0):

```
node *head = nullptr;
```

`head` is `NULL`

```
temp1 = head;
```

`temp1` becomes `NULL`

```
while(temp1->next!=nullptr) {
```

`temp1` is `NULL`, hence `temp1->next` is dereferencing a `NULL` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Your program started the iteration through the list with an empty `head` pointer.  If you look at it in a debugger, head will be still NULL because you never set it.

```
node *temp1, *temp2, *temp3;

temp1 = new node();
temp1->value = 1;
temp1->next = nullptr;
head= temp;   // link to head

temp2 = new node();
temp2->value = 2;
temp2->next = nullptr;
temp1->next= temp2;  // link 1 -> 2

temp3 = new node();
temp3->value = 3;
temp3->next = nullptr;
temp2->next= temp3;   // link 2 -> 3

// now we have head -> temp1 -> temp2 -> temp3

// now use temp1 as iterator starting with head
temp1 = head;
while(temp1->next!=nullptr) {
    printf("%d\n", temp1->value);
    temp1 = temp1->next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning:

```
node *head = 0;
// ...
temp1 = head;

while(temp1->next!=nullptr) { // temp1 is null here
    temp1 = temp1->next;
}
```

Additionally `temp1->next` won't be null either. You should initialize it:

```
#define NULL 0

class node {
public:
    node(int value, node *next) { 
      this.value = value;
      this.next = next;
    }
    int value;
    node *next;
};

// ..
node *n3 = new node(1, NULL);
node *n2 = new node(1, n3);
node *n1 = new node(1, n2);
```

Answer (score 0):

That article gives a reasonable explanation of how to create a Linked List in C, and it uses C++ comments, but it is a terrible explanation of how to create a linked list in C++.

Let me walk you away from the C-mindset there and start you on a path to encapsulationenment.

Typically each element in a linked list is called a "node", and for each node there is a pointer to one or more other nodes in the list. In a "singly linked list" it is to the next node, in a "doubly linked list" there is a pointer to the node before and the node after, to allow us to go backwards as well as forwards.

An important early decision is how you want to encapsulate this pointing. You can choose either to have a simple "Node" class, private to the List class, which has prev/next pointers and a discrete "void*" pointer to the actual data itself. This is a very C-like approach, because it throws away type information. Ah - but you could store the type as a enum or something? You could, and that's a great C solution.

But C++ is all about encapsulation. Being a Node of a List is a well-defined and fairly discrete role with a simple set of properties and attributes. It is perfect for encapsulation as a simple base class.

```
class ListNode
{
    ListNode* m_next;
    ListNode() : m_next(NULL) {}

    ListNode* next() { return m_next; }

    // return the last node in my current chain.
    ListNode* tail() {
        ListNode* node = this;
        while (node->next() != nullptr)
            node = node->next();
        return node;
    }

    // insert a new node at this point in the chain,
    // think about what happens if newNode->next() is not null tho.
    bool linkTo(ListNode* newNode);
};
```

An equally important encapsulation question, though, is whether or not you want anyone to be able to come along and call the ListNode members, or if you want to restrict their visibility to accessors of the List itself. There are certainly patterns where it can be helpful to deal with abstract "ListNode*" without need to know which list they belong to. But a singly-linked list has limitations - for example, without knowing the list itself, you can't ever remove an entry (how do you know who was pointing TO you?)

However, this allows us to do

```
class Product : public ListNode {
    string m_name;
    std::vector<float> m_priceHistory;
public:
    Product(const std::string& name_)
        : ListNode()
        , m_name(name_)
        , m_priceHistory()
        {}
    void save();
};

class Book : public Product { ... };
class DVD : public Product { ... };

List productList;

productList.add(new Book("hello world"));
productList.add(new DVD("lose wait: lose a limb"));
productList.add(new Insurance("dietary related gangrene"));
...
for(ListNode* node = productList.head(); node != nullptr; node = node->next()) {
    node->save();
}
```

Another approach would take us back to the first ListNode idea, the more C like one; the problem wasn't that it used a pointer, but that it threw away type information. "void" is primarily there for when you want to say "the type of this pointer doesn't mater". The downside is, "the type of this pointer goes away". We can fix that, with templates.

```
template<typename T> // T will be an alias for whatever type we have to deal with.
class List
{
    struct  Node* m_list;

public:
    struct  Node
    {
        Node* m_next;
        T* m_data;
        Node() : m_next(nullptr), m_data(nullptr) {}
        Node* next() const { return m_next; }
        bool linkTo(Node* newPredecessor);
        bool link(Node* newFollower);
    };

public:
    List() : m_list(nullptr) {}

    Node* head() { return m_next; }
    Node* tail() {
        if (m_list == nullptr)
            return nullptr;
        for (Node* node = m_list; node->m_next != nullptr; node = node->m_next)
            {}
        return node;
    }
    void insert(T* data) { // add to head of the list
        Node* node = new Node(data);
        node->m_next = m_head;
        m_head = node;
    }
    Node* append(T* data) {
        if (head() == nullptr)
            insert(data);
        else {
            Node* node = new Node(data);
            Node* tail = this->tail(); // could get expensive.
            tail->link(node);
        }
        return node;
    }
};

List<Product> productList;
productList.append(new Book("Gone with the money"));
productList.append(new DVD("that's no moon"));
productList.append(new Pet("llama"));
```

An advantage of this approach is that we don't have to add additional members/clutter to the definition of our data. The disadvantages are that we use more memory - each node requires two pointers and that nodes don't have an easy way to tell you if/where they are in the list (you have to search all nodes and find the one that points to your item).

There is also a usage-determined cost/benefit in terms of the memory allocations.

There is also still a major C-esque component to this latest iteration, the Node class is far too visible. Ideally, it should be entirely private to the end user. But since data elements have no way of telling where they are in the list, it would be impossible to walk over the list.

What you want is to hide the Node definition, so that only list can see it (no, it's ok, you really don't need the ability to change 'm_next') and create a secondary class that provides the functionality we'd need without letting us do anything we shouldn't.

```
public:
    class Iterator
    {
        Node* m_node;
    public:
        Iterator(Node* node_=nullptr) : m_node(node_) {}

        bool advance() {
            if (isValid())
                m_node = m_node->m_next;
            return isValid();
        }
        T* data() {
            return isValid() ? m_node->m_data : nullptr;
        }
        bool isValid() const { return (m_node != nullptr); }
        bool isTail() const { return isValid() && (m_node->m_next != nullptr); }

        // if you feel the need to get seriously advanced,
        // overload operator "++" to allow ++it;
        // overload operator "*" to allow (*it) to get m_data
        // overload operator "=" to allow Iterator* it = list->head();
    };

    // in class list:
        Iterator head() { return Iterator(m_head); }
        Iterator tail() {
            Iterator it(m_head);
            while (!it.isTail()) {
                it.advance();
            }
            return it;
        }
        Iterator find(const T& data_) { return find(&data_); }
        Iterator find(const T* data_) {
            for (Iterator it = head(); it.isValid(); it.advance()) {
                if(it.data() == data_)
                    return it;
            }
        }
```

Hope this is enough to give you plenty of ideas :)